# share array of objects between iphone and apple watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

I want to send array of objects from iPhone to the WatchKit extension using WatchKit connectivity.

I tried to use `sendMessageData` but it only accepts `NSData`.

Also how to share the same class between both iPhone and WatchKit extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sendMessage(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)` which sends a dictionary of property list values.

To share the same class between iPhone and Watch Extension just add it to both targets:

[image]

Comment: Sharing the class works fine,Thank you .
About first part of the question, Do you mean to send the object properties as a dictionary to the watch instead of sending the object itself ?

Comment: You can only send objects to the watch as NSData or a dictionary of property list values (array, dictionary, string, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, Boolean). Anything else has to be serialized to one of those types)